# dynamic links creation different in ie

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, internet-explorer, split

My string:

```
"<SPAN style=\"COLOR: #000000; PADDING-RIGHT: 30px\">Reason 1:</SPAN> My Text Here!"
```

Internet Explorer:

```
"SPANstyleCOLOR000000PADDINGRIGHT30pxReason1SPANMyTextHere"
```

Other Browsers:

```
"Reason1BankbeatingexchangeratesCompareourratestoday"

// Remove all characters, keep alphanumerical + spaces 
reasonTitleSpaces = reasonTitle.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\s]+/g, '');

// Remove all characters, keep alphanumerical
reasonTitle = reasonTitle.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9]+/g, '');
```

Comment: Can you provide the original value of `$(this).html()`. I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but string maniulation of HTML is never the answer.

Comment: added one example @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: So I am grabbing dynamic content from the page that is 90% of the time the same formatting, and creating links from it.

Comment: @Anicho: Would you expect `"Reason 1:"` from that example?

Comment: no I am trimming `reason` and removing the `:` and replacing it with `1.`

Comment: @DavidPärsson gotten rid of the excess code you can see where the problem actual exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the jQuery API to create the link instead of manipulating it as string...

This will give you better results and cross-browser compatibility.

Instead of `reasonTitle = $(this).html();`, clone the DOM structure so you can freely manipulate without changing the page:

```
<script>
reasonTitle = $(this).clone();

//Remove the span tag, now you have only the reason
reasonTitle.find('span').remove()

//Get the text value
reasonTitle = $.trim(reasonTitle.text());

//Create the anchor
anchorLink = $("<a />",{id:'anchor', name:reasonTitle})
$(this).parent().before(anchorLink);

//You don't need to count your `<li>`, use `<ol>` for ordinal lists
//Create the link:
$("<a />",{href:'#'+reasonTitle}).click(function(){
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', experimentConversionReference, 'ReasonClicked', $(this).text()]);
}).text(reasonTitle );
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's dirty but it does the job

```
// Remove extras for IE
reasonTitle = reasonTitle.split("Reason").slice(1).join("Reason");
reasonTitleSpaces = reasonTitleSpaces.split("Reason").slice(1).join("Reason");

// Remove any extra occurances of "span" for IE
reasonTitle = reasonTitle.replace("SPAN","");
reasonTitleSpaces = reasonTitleSpaces.replace("SPAN","");
```